# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 login.php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi previous problem was already solved now it returns this error..

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog 
name: 1046 No database selected' in /home/u708894430/public_html/php/login.php:12 Stack trace: #0
/home/u708894430/public_html/php/login.php(12): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in 
/home/u708894430/public_html/php/login.php on line 12
```

Here's my login.php code:

```
<?php
if($_POST){
session_start();
require("config.php");
require('general.php');
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$errors = array();
if ($email&&$pass){
$qry = $handler->prepare( "SELECT `email` FROM 'login' WHERE `email` = ?" );
$qry->bindValue( 1, $email );
$qry->execute();
$row = $qry->rowCount();

  if ($row == 1){
    $qry = $handler->prepare( "SELECT * FROM 'login' WHERE email = ? AND stat = '1'" );
    $qry->bindValue( 1, $email );
    $qry->execute();
    $row = $qry->rowCount();
        if ($row == '1'){ 
        $userData = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $hash = hash('sha256',$userData['salt'].hash('sha256',$pass));


          if($hash == $userData['password']){
            $_SESSION['email']=$email;
            header('Location:/../lab/profile.php');
          }
          else{
            $errors = "<center>The Password/Email you Entered is incorrect. Please check your login Details and <br><a href='/../lab/login.php' style='font-size:12px;text-decoration:none;'>Login Again</a> or if you do not have an account yet please register <a href='/../lab/register.php' style='text-decoration:none;'>here</a></center>";
          }
        } 

        else{
          $errors = "Your Account is not yet activated. Please check your email."; 
        }
   }
  else{
    $errors = "<center>The Password/Email you Entered is incorrect. Please check your login Details and <br><a href='/../lab/login.php' style='font-size:12px;text-decoration:none;'>Login Again</a> or if you do not have an account yet please register <a href='/../lab/register.php' style='text-decoration:none;'>here</a></center>";
  }
}
else{
$errors = "Please fill in the Email and Password fields to login";
}
}
?>
```

I don't know what's wrong in my code? It's working fine on my local server. but when i migrated it to live server this error occurred.
Thanks

Comment: Column names should be enclosed in backticks (`), not single quotes ('). Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Same is true for table names. I agree, close it.

Comment: it worked but now it returns another error:
    'SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name 1046 No database   selected'

it says no database selected. but database name in my config.php file is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1046 No database selected

You can fix this either during the connection to mysql, or within the queries. Pretend our database name is `foo`.

- Don't quote table names, use backticks (`) if you want

#### Within the query

```
SELECT `email` FROM foo.`login` WHERE `email` = ?
```

#### Within the connection

- Supply the `dbname=<>` parameter. For example;

```
dbname=foo
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php